# Excel VBA Print Data Rows Only

Tags: vba, excel

Hi  I would like to print a range regarding E Column ...

Print the range based on the E Column Data rows. I used xlCellTypeBlanks method but it is not help , because **E Column cells have formulas.** So I need to print only Data Rows of E Column,not the formula blank cells

Here is my code

```
Columns("B:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Columns("I:N").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Dim r1, r2 As Range
Set r1 = Range("B:D")
Set r2 = Range("I:N")
Range("E4:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
ActiveSheet.Range(r1, r2).PrintPreview
```

Comment: you may want to 1) post your so far code 2) give more details about what it does but shouldn't and what it should do but doesn't

Comment: Could you filter the data to exclude any rows where column E is blank, then do the print?

Comment: Ok... Then How do I filter the data in VBA

Comment: record a Macro: start recording, do the needed filtering in Excel, stop the recording and see the generated code

Comment: BTW, be informed that `Range(r1, r2)` will reference cells ranging from the topleftmost cell down to the bottomrightmost one of the two ranges: in your case it'll reference all cells of columns between "B" to "N" (them included). If you want to reference cells of range `r1` _and_ range `r2` then use `Union(r1, r2)`